# How can I find the intersection length of a circle and a rectangle?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have the following information:

- The coordinates of the vertices of the rectangle.
- The radius and center position of the circle.

How can I find the length of the red line in the picture? (The rectangle isn't necessarily aligned with the X and Y axes, might be 'rotated').

Edit: if the circle is in diagonal to one of the corners of the rectangle, I still need the same thing. Like so:

[image]

Comment: What is given? Do you have a ruler?

Comment: @barakmanos I added the known info to the question

Comment: do you need the answer for a general geometry?

Comment: @B-Brock What does that mean? I need the answer for when I know the vertices of the rectangle and the radius and center of the circle.

Comment: like, what do you look for if the circle lies diagonally from one of the corners?

Comment: @B-Brock See my edit please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the length of the line segment overlap of a cross with arm length $r$ with a rectangle, where the edges of the rectangle and the arms of the cross are aligned.

First, rotate your reference frame so the rectangle is aligned with the axes (maybe not what you were looking for).

If your rectangle is defined by bottom left and top right corners $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, and your cross is defined by center $(x_0,y_0)$ and arm-length $r$, then you perform this algorithm:

```
if x0 < x1: // to the left
    if y0 < y1: // bottom diagonal
        overlap = 0
    elif y0 < y2: // left center
        overlap = max(r - (x1 - x0),0)
    else: // top diagonal
        overlap = 0
elif x0 < x2: // in center
    if y0 < y1: // bottom
        overlap = min(max(r - (y1 - y0),0), y2 -y1)
    elif y0 < y2: // center
        overlap_up = min(r, (y2 - y0))
        overlap_down = min(r, (y0 - y1))
        overlap_right = min(r, (x2 - x0))
        overlap_left = min(r, (x0 - x1))
        overlap_vertical = overlap_up + overlap_down
        overlap_horizontal = overlap_left + overlap_right
        overlap = overlap_vertical + overlap_horizontal
    else: // top center
        overlap = min(max(r - (y0 - y2),0), y2 -y1)
else: // to the right
    if y0 < y1: // bottom diagonal
        overlap = 0
    elif y0 < y2: // right center
        overlap = max(r - (x0 - x2), 0)
    else: // top diagonal
        overlap = 0
```

Comment: Then why is the (x2,y2) relevant? It isn't in the formula.

Comment: Also, does this work if the rectangle isn't aligned with the two axes?

Comment: did this answer your question? did I treat the diagonal and center cases correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the equation of the line L1 which cuts the the circle using two point form. And then homogenize the equation of circle to find the intersection points and use those two points to form another line equation L2 using two point form and then find another line L3 parallel to L2 but which is a tangent to the circle. At last find the shortest distance between L2 and L3 using the formula d= |Ax1+By1+C/ √(A^2 +B^2)|